# Как заменить параметры атрибута в svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```css
#circle3 {
  background: #cde9f2;
}

#circle2 {
  background: #6e3e20;
}

#circle1 {
  background: #027831;
}

.color {
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.color:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.color a {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(181, 181, 181) 53%, rgb(235, 235, 235) 52%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(181, 181, 181) 53%, rgb(235, 235, 235) 52%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(181, 181, 181) 53%, rgb(235, 235, 235) 52%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(181, 181, 181) 53%, rgb(235, 235, 235) 52%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(181, 181, 181) 53%, rgb(235, 235, 235) 52%);
}

.color a span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.color a.active span {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="colorMask1" >
      <feFlood  flood-color="#027831" result="flood" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="flood" operator="arithmetic" k1="1" k2="0" k3="0" k4="0" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/HP_logo_630x630.png" filter="url(#colorMask1)" />
</svg>

  <div class="color">
    <a rel="#027831" id="circle1" href="#flood-color"></a>
    <a rel="#6e3e20" id="circle2" href="#flood-color"></a>
    <a rel="#cde9f2" id="circle3" href="#flood-color"></a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<defs>
<filter id="colorMask1" >
  <feFlood  flood-color="#027831" result="flood" />
  <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="flood" operator="arithmetic" k1="1" k2="0" k3="0" k4="0" />
</filter>
</defs>
<image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/HP_logo_630x630.png" filter="url(#colorMask1)" />
</svg>

<div class="color">
<a rel="#027831" id="circle1" href="#flood-color"></a>
<a rel="#6e3e20" id="circle2" href="#flood-color"></a>
<a rel="#cde9f2" id="circle3" href="#flood-color"></a>
</div>
```

Как передать параметр (например `#6e3e20`) атрибуту `flood-color` по клику на

```
<a rel="#6e3e20" id="circle2" href="#flood-color"></a>
```

Comment: Ну что за извращение... В `SVG` растровую графику пихать... :(

Comment: SVG в данном случае выступает фильтром и это на мой взгляд самое оптимальное решение для каталога продукции с функциеей окрашивание растра.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так :DDD

```js
jQuery('.color a').on('click', function () {
  var b = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
  jQuery('#colorMask1 feFlood').attr({'flood-color': b});
});
```

```css
#circle3 { 
       background:#cde9f2;
    }
    #circle2 { 
       background:#6e3e20;
    }
    #circle1 { 
       background:#027831;
    }
    .color {
     padding:5px 0;
     position:relative;
    }

    .color:after {
     content: ".";
     display: block;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
     line-height: 0;
     height: 0;
    }

    .color a {
     display:block;
     width:25px;
     height:25px;
     -moz-border-radius:3px;
     -webkit-border-radius:3px;
     border-radius:3px;
     text-indent:100%;
     white-space:nowrap;
     overflow:hidden;
     float:left;
     margin:2px;
     background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(181,181,181) 53%, rgb(235,235,235) 52%);
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(181,181,181) 53%, rgb(235,235,235) 52%);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(181,181,181) 53%, rgb(235,235,235) 52%);
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(181,181,181) 53%, rgb(235,235,235) 52%);
     background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(181,181,181) 53%, rgb(235,235,235) 52%);
    }

    .color a span {
     display:block;
     height:100%;
    }

    .color a.active span {
     border:2px solid yellow;
     height:21px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        </head>
        <body>

    <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
      <defs>
        <filter id="colorMask1" >
          <feFlood  flood-color="#027831" result="flood" />
          <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="flood" operator="arithmetic" k1="1" k2="0" k3="0" k4="0" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/HP_logo_630x630.png" filter="url(#colorMask1)" />
    </svg>

        <div class="color">
         <a rel="#027831" id="circle1" href="#flood-color"></a>
         <a rel="#6e3e20" id="circle2" href="#flood-color"></a>
         <a rel="#cde9f2" id="circle3" href="#flood-color"></a>
        </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!
Thank you very much for your help!